# Excel - IF formula for multiple cells

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have 5 cells with either 1, 0 and -1 values.

I want to build a formula that allows me to have, for example, a 0 or a -1 if any of those 5 cells are a 0 or a -1.

Can you please help? Thanks.

Comment: Can you elaborate your question? I'm currently not sure what you're asking. Some example data would also be helpful.

Comment: Welcome to Super User. We are not a script writing service. We expect users to tell us what they have tried so far (including any scripts they are using) and where they're stuck so that we can help with specific problems. Questions that only ask for scripts are too broad and are likely to be [put on hold or closed](http://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions). Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: You should also [edit] your question to include some example (mock) data (before and after). See [Format Text as a Table](http://www.sensefulsolutions.com/2010/10/format-text-as-table.html) for a web utility that will help you to create a nice data table you can paste into your question.

Comment: What do you want if the 5 cells contain **both** a 0 and a -1?

Answer (score 0):

To test for any **zero**s, use:

```
=IF(COUNTIF(A1:A5,0)>0,0,"")
```

and to test for any **-1**'s, use:

```
=IF(COUNTIF(A1:A5,-1)>0,-1,"")
```